How can I implement moment matching with kernel tricks if I do not have the complete distribution but only the higher-order moments or culuments?
As is said in Appendix B.3 of ref, "It is difficult to match high-order moments, because we have to deal with high order tensors directly. On the other hand, MMD can easily match high-order moments (even infinite order moments by using Gaussian kernel) with kernel tricks, and enjoys strong theoretical guarantee."
However, if I only know little information about the true distribution such as some higher-order moments or cumulants, how can I match these information with kernel tricks?
